# Handle Authentication in AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following code in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResultsAll(string keyword)
{
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
 string data = "Search results for " + keyword;
 return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and trying an AJAX call as following

```
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/SearchResultsAll",
type: 'POST',
data: {
 keyword: searchString                        
},
  success: function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR) { 
  console.log("ERROR");},
  complete: function (jqXHR, status) { 
  console.log("DONE"); 
  }
});
```

Instead of getting the string back, I get the HTML code for my `login` page - Yes the authentication is active on my `HomeController`

How do I tackle this in AJAX calls?

Comment: Use `AllowAnonymousAttribute` (i.e. `[AllowAnonymous]`) if you want to allow anonymous users to use search form.

Comment: Alternatively, if `SearchResultsAll()` does require authorization, then the GET that rendered that page should also have an `[Authorize]` attribute

Comment: Cheers, it worked - I think using `[AllowAnonymous]` for search is ok as it only returns results on based of user ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with applying Authorize globally is that you have to be logged on (authorized) before you can log on or register.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult SearchResultsAll(string keyword)
{
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
 string data = "Search results for " + keyword;
 return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

`AllowAnonymous` Attribute that helps you secure an entire ASP.NET MVC 4 Website or Controller while providing a convenient means of allowing anonymous users access to certain controller actions, like the login and register Actions